# Trouble installing DateTime from CPAN

Tags: perl, module, cpan

I'm trying to install the DateTime module. I went into CPAN from a terminal and started the install with make. It ran for hours and when it finally stopped, the last line simply said 'killed'. My perl script using the module still won't compile, it says *Can't locate DateTime.pm in @INC (you may need to install the DateTime module)*

I searched the file system and found the following:

```
/home/kelly/.cpan/build/DateTime-1.54-0/lib/DateTime
/home/kelly/.cpan/build/DateTime-Locale-1.33-1/lib/DateTime
/home/kelly/.cpan/build/DateTime-1.54-1/lib/DateTime
/home/kelly/.cpan/build/DateTime-Locale-1.33-0/lib/DateTime
```

So apparently the module is there but Perl can't find it?

I had previously tried installing the module and stopped it because I thought it was in an infinite loop. Also, I had previously installed some updates and hadn't restarted the computer yet. But it doesn't seem likely that either of those interfered...

Comment: What Linux distribution or unix-like OS are you using?    If Linux, DateTime is almost certainly available as a package for your distro (e.g. `sudo apt-get install libdatetime-perl` on debian and derivatives).    BTW, note that the ~/.cpan/build/ directory is the directory that cpan uses to **build** a module before installing it.  It is not the final built module.    The last line you mention, "killed", is nowhere near enough info to determine the cause of the build failure.  You'll need to read and understand previous lines.   What kind of system are you building on? a PC with lots of RAM?

Comment: Or a tiny system with very little RAM or disk space?  Also note that DateTime depends on the XSLoader module.  This means that at least part of the module is compiled code, rather than interpreted perl-native code, and requires a compiler like `gcc` to be installed and working.    And, DateTime is a library module with numerous dependencies - the build failure may be in one of those modules rather than in DateTime itself.  This is yet another reason why you should install a pre-built package rather than build it yourself - all those dependencies will already be built and packaged.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm supposed to reply here or edit the OP. I'm running Linux Mint 20.1 on a relatively old laptop, and I have very little experence. I thought I was installing a pre-built package. Oh, and I just confirmed I have gcc installed. I have a screenshot of what came before the "killed" statement, but I don't see a way to upload that. Wherever I can get a pre-built package, I would happily use that, just tell me where... when I searched, all I found was CPAN and the instructions I used...

Comment: I tried again with install instead of make, and it worked. Back in business, writing my script... Thank you!

Comment: According to https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/libdatetime-perl it seems to be packaged, with the same name as in debian and ubuntu, which is not surprising as most things in debian & ubuntu end up in mint.   Try the `sudo apt-get install ...` command from my first comment.